# How to assign permissions for a CPT to a user

Tags: custom-post-types, users

I have a list of CPT's called resources.  I want each resource to be assignable to any number of users.  The assignment would preferably occur by an admin, logging in, nav'ing to that users email, and seeing a checkbox list of all available resources, they could then check a box next to resource A, and then the user has access to resource A. There will be like 150 resources so its not a short list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something you can achieve with the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin. The trick is to use the [`ACF_LITE`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to/including-acf-in-a-plugin-theme/) mode, which would let you define a dynamic list of user profile fields from `functions.php`. You could iterate over each post type and display a checkbox for it. Then use the [`edit_user_profile_update`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile_update) hook to call `$user->add_cap('edit_[resource]')` or `$user->remove_cap('edit_[resource]')`, etc.

Comment: I was unable to find the ACF_LITE reference on the ACF site.  Any more clarity you can provide?

Comment: Ah, yes, I've linked ACF_LITE up above to add some context.